# Is it always true that an integral diverges on (a,b) if it diverges on (c,b) and a<c<b?

Tags: improper-integrals

I know that the integral of 1/x diverges on (0,b).  I know the same integral still diverges on (-b, b), despite the fact it seems it should be zero.  My question then is, "Is it ALWAYS the case that if an integral diverges on a subinterval of an interval, it must then diverge on the larger interval?".

Comment: With the usual calculus textbook definitions, yes. However, check out [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) on wikipedia.